# How can I make sure all cells (not only the visible ones) are loaded in a tableview before didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Storyboard]
I am coding a quiz app. As you can see in the storyboard, there are 2 tableviews. In the first one you select the type of the exam and in the second one you see the question. The way I designed the app is, there are 2 different kind of cells. Question and Multiple Choice.

The first cell of the 2nd tableView is the question cell and the remaining 4 are multipleChoice cells.(You will see 6 cells in the storyboard.In the last one I am trying to show ads.But that's irrelevant to this question.So think of it as 5 cells in total)

If the selected answer is right, I set the selected cell's contentView background color to green. If it is wrong, I set the selected cell's contentView background color to red and make the correct answer blink in green by using an extension.Here is the extension...

```
extension UIView{

func blink() {

    self.alpha = 0.2
    self.backgroundColor = .green
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {self.alpha = 1.0}, completion: nil)


}

func stopBlink() {
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    layer.removeAllAnimations()
    alpha = 1

}
}
```

And here is the code that achieves this

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)

    if indexPath.row == dogruCevapInt && isCompleted == false && sonrakiVCyeAktarilacakIsTimeUp == false {

        // The answer is right 

        print("Doğru Cevap")
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
        dogrular = dogrular + 1

        updateNavigationItemTitle()

        if let dogruCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SecenekTableViewCell {

            let originalBGColor = dogruCell.contentView.backgroundColor
            dogruCell.contentView.backgroundColor = .green

            playSound(soundState: SettingsSingleton.shared.isSoundOn!,soundName: "correct", fileExtension: "mp3")


            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false, block: { (newTimer) in
                dogruCell.contentView.backgroundColor = originalBGColor

                self.nextQuestion()
            })
        }


    }else if indexPath.row != 0 && isCompleted == false && sonrakiVCyeAktarilacakIsTimeUp == false {

        // The answer is wrong

        print("Yanlış Cevap. Doğrusu \(dogruCevap)")

        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false

        yanlislar = yanlislar + 1

        updateNavigationItemTitle()



        if let yanlisCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SecenekTableViewCell {

            let originalBGColor = yanlisCell.contentView.backgroundColor
            yanlisCell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
            playSound(soundState: SettingsSingleton.shared.isSoundOn!,soundName: "wrong", fileExtension: "wav")

            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.dogruCevapInt, section: indexPath.section), at: .bottom, animated: true)


            if let dogruCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: dogruCevapInt, section: indexPath.section)) {

                dogruCell.contentView.backgroundColor = .green
                dogruCell.blink()
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false, block: { (newTimer) in
                    dogruCell.stopBlink()
                    yanlisCell.contentView.backgroundColor = originalBGColor

                    self.nextQuestion()
                    dogruCell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
                })
            }else {
                //The right answer is currently not visible
                //We cannot make it blink let's at least go to the next question 

                self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false, block: { (newTimer) in

                    self.nextQuestion()

                })
            }

        }


    }else if isCompleted == true {
        print("Is Completed true")
    }else {
        //If the user selects the question
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }

}
```

and now the problem...

Everything works perfect if all the multiple choice cells are currently visible(or at least some part of it is visible)on the screen. But if the cell that holds the right answer is not visible, I cannot make it blink no matter what I try. How do I do this?

I recorded a video and converted it into animated gif. Please see the 5th question to see what I mean.

[Screen Recording of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7nAf.jpg)

Comment: Never manipulate the **view** (the cell). Modify the **model** (the data source) and the **controller** will update the UI in `cellForRow` when the cell becomes visible.

Comment: The model comes from a Realm database. I could not figure out how to achieve this via using the model.  Thank you for your help

Comment: If the row isn't visible then the tableview won't have a cell for that row; a cell will only be allocated once that row is scrolled into view. As @vadian says you need to track the selection in some sort of view model or state property and set the cell properties appropriately in `cellForRow`

Comment: I tried scrolling programmatically and sending the blink command afterwards.Even that does not work.Like you both said I believe I need to find a different approach.